# how to insert a function into column

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

i have table with name of function is in it, example tbl_1

| name | formula |
| --- | --- |
| rectangular | wide(h,w) |
| circle | area(p, r) |

the question is, is there a way to get the function through the column, like:

```
select col_1,  col_2, (select formula from tbl_1 where name = 'rectangular') 
from tbl_2
```

i keep get the string of the function, not the result,
thank you for your help

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is in `tbl_2`?

Answer (score 0):

simple inner join

```
select t1.name , t2.formula
from tbl_1 t1 join tbl_2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
```